# How to Recover drivers when upgrading from XP to Ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I have an old computer running on windows XP which Im going to convert to Ubuntu using whole disk (not dual boot), will I lose my CD/DVD and memory card readers drivers? How do I re-install drivers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will lose everything. Be informed that windows and Linux are completely different operating system, and even if you retain a copy of windows driver it is use less in Ubuntu (Or derivative). But Cheer that, Ubuntu will support CD/DVD drive and memory card reader out of the box, in most probable case you will not require separate drivers. Happy journey ahead with Ubuntu.